# How to do a 301 redirect of dynamic pages with query strings to static pages?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I used to have a photo gallery that dynamically generated 1 page per photo, assigning each page's url a unique query string, such as:

https://www.example.com/photos/index.php?start=1
and
https://www.example.com/photos/index.php?start=2

Since I don't have a ton of photos in my gallery, I've turned each page into static urls (which might help their seo rankings). Those same pages now have static urls such as:

https://www.example.com/photos/winterstorm2007.php
and
https://www.example.com/photos/new-chickens.php

Here is what I tried in the htaccess file inside my photos directory -- which just throws a 404 error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index\.php?start=1 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /photos/winterstorm2007.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index\.php?start=2 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /photos/pastured-chickens.php [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QUERY_STRING` variable only contains query part after `?` in URL.

You may use `THE_REQUEST` to match REQUEST_URI and query:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?start=1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /photos/winterstorm2007.php? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?start=2\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /photos/pastured-chickens.php? [R=301,L]
```

Also note trailing `?` in target URI to strip off previous query strings.

Comment: thank you for your reply.

the good news is that i no longer get the 404 error.

and it does work properly for start=1 and start=2.

however, i quickly expanded your code to include 20 more redirects and whether i visit

https://www.example.com/photos/index.php?start=1

OR

https://www.example.com/photos/index.php?start=15

they both now redirect to the first static page:

https://www.example.com/photos/winterstorm2007.php

so it appears to be acting immediately upon the first digit in the start variable.

Comment: ok in that case add `\s` after pattern as in my updated answer.

Comment: 100% ABSOLUTELY PERFECT! THANK YOU!